# SQL extract numbers from string and convert to int

Tags: sql

I have a table `packages` with `pack_id` and `speed` columns.
I have the following values for speed:

```
1.5Mbps, 10Mbps, 12Mbps, 2.5Mbps, 5Mbps, 750Kbps
```

How can I convert that to a numeric column of speeds?
Thanks,
Tamir

Comment: maybe cut the number from the string with String functions.(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) Then adding both parts to one column each. It would be best to have another table that stores all possible speednames like `Mbps`, `Kpbs` etc. and then reffering to there pk and only storing that key in the table `packages`.

Comment: If they are the only actual textual values you'll have in there just a simple `REPLACE` on Mbps & Kbps with an empty string and then casting it to a numeric value might be enough.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? You've already got two product specific answers, hope you aren't wasting their time writing answer for wrong dbms.

Comment: Are all those values in one row, as comma separated items - or is it several rows?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please clarify the title as it says "convert to int". Your speed values are clearly not `int`

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a sample as per your requirement please check. Please take a note that sample prepared for sql-server.

search following subjects based on your DBMS.

1. for SQL Server: `PATINDEX`
2. for Oracle : `REGEXP_LIKE`
3. for oracle: `REGEXP`

The following is for SQL Server

```
declare @Speed as varchar(50)='1.5Mbps'

select Left(
      SubString(@Speed, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', @Speed), 8000), 
      PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString(@Speed, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', @Speed), 8000) + 'X')-1)
```

You can learn more about 'PATINDEX' from below given link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188395.aspx

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way you can achieve this based on your database. I tried it using teradata sql, that will give you idea about logic which you can implement according to your database:

**Simple substr instr approach:**

```
select substr(speed,1,instr(speed,'bps')-2);
```

**Regex Approach**

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR (speed, '[\d.]*');
```

One thing you overlooked in your question is about UOM of speed. values are populated as Kbps and Mbps both so in case of Kbps you need to convert into Mbps as well.